# How to add Rfc3339 date time string to add one second in c#

Tags: c#, rfc3339

I have this date time string 2020-06-30T20:59:59.415Z. now i have to add 1 second for this date time string. i am converting this to date time this date time are convert to other format and date time are convert to other date time. so please explain hoe i can do add one second

format required  yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ

Thanks,
KD

Comment: Paste your code please!

Comment: `var states = new List<string>();
states.Add("COMPLETED");
var stateFilter = new SearchOrdersStateFilter.Builder(states: states).Build()

string datetimeString = "2020-06-30T20:59:59.415Z";
var closedAt = new TimeRange.Builder().StartAt(datetimeString).Build();

var dateTimeFilter = new SearchOrdersDateTimeFilter.Builder().ClosedAt(closedAt).Build();
var filter = new SearchOrdersFilter.Builder().StateFilter(stateFilter).DateTimeFilter(dateTimeFilter).Build();`

Comment: @Keyur You're supposed to edit your question.

Comment: `var datetime = DateTime.Parse("2020-06-30T20:59:59.415Z");
var result = datetime.AddSeconds(1);`

Comment: I had try this `var datetime = DateTime.Parse("2020-06-30T20:59:59.415Z");`
`var result = datetime.AddSeconds(1);`

but this changing time to other timezone.

Comment: @Keyur `.ToString("o")` will convert it back to a string.

Answer (score 0):

This the code and convert this to other time

var datetime = DateTime.Parse("2020-06-30T20:59:59.415Z");
Result: {7/1/2020 2:29:59 AM}

var result = datetime.AddSeconds(1);
Result: {7/1/2020 2:30:00 AM}

string dtstr = result.ToString("o");
Result: 2020-07-01T02:30:00.4150000+05:30

**required result is:  2020-06-30T21:00:00.415Z**